# Ruby - Get timezone offset from latitude and longitude for specific date and time

Tags: ruby, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I am using the [timezone](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone) gem to obtain the time zone from latitude and longitude. I need the time zone for some solar calculations. The API I use requires the timezone offset (**without** the daylight). For example now (`2021/10/12 12:37`) in UK with BST time the timezone offset for the API would be zero. With `timezone` though I would get 3600

```
tz = Timezone.lookup(51.51, 0.1)
=> #<Timezone::Zone name: "Europe/London">
tz.utc_offset
=> 3600
```

That's easy. I can check for daylight saving and correct.

```
(tz.dst?) ? (tz.utc_offset) : (tz.utc_offset - 3600)
```

I can do the same for another time (I do all the calculations in 2010) as long as it is in my locale timezone.

If I try, say, Melbourne, I am not able to create a time in that location and check the daylight saving. I am sure I am doing something wrong. Am I overthinking it?

For example:

```
tz = Timezone.lookup(-37.814, 145)
=> #<Timezone::Zone name: "Australia/Melbourne">
tz.utc_offset
=> 39600 ((10 + 1)h)
```

This is now (`2021/10/12 12:37`), but for my API to work this should be 10 because daylight should not be included.

My idea was to take a reference time, 2010/01/01 01:00 and make all the calculations for that time. The problem is that I don't know how I can create a time in a specific time zone and check whether that time is a daylight time.

I have tried

```
reftime = tz.time(Time.new(2010,1,1,1,0))
```

but if do

```
reftime = tz.time(Time.new(2010,1,1,1,0))
reftime.dst?
```

I get `false`, but it should be true.

How can I check whether a specific date in a specific location is in daylight saving mode?

Answer (score 0):

Melbourne has started daylight saving at 2021-10-03 03:00:00.  So it's using AEDT but not AEST.